# Proving a theorem related to convex cone

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional real Euclidean space. Let $C$ be a non-empty convex cone in $V$. I need to prove that the following are equivalent.

1. int($C$) is non-empty.
2. $C$ contains a basis of $V$.
3. $C-C=V$.

I have proved 1 implies 3 and 2 implies 3. I tried proving 3 implies 2 as follows.

Let $C-C=V$. I need to prove that $C$ contains a basis of $V$. Suppose C doesn't contain a basis of V. Let $\{v_{1},...v_{r}\}$ be a maximal linearly independent set in $C$ where $r<n$=dim$V$. I know that $C-C$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ containing $C$. So if I can prove that $C \subset  span\{v_{1},...v_{r}\}$ which is a proper subspace of $V=C-C$, I will get a contradiction. But I'm not able to prove that $C \subset  span\{v_{1},...v_{r}\}$.

Is my approach correct? Can someone help to prove it?! Also I need help to prove either 2 implies 1 or 3 implies 1.

Comment: Can you explain please what do you mean with $C-C$?

Comment: C-C={x-y | x,y in C}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C\subseteq\text{span}\{v_1,\cdots,v_r\}$ as follows (starting with your work, which is good): suppose not, then there is a vector $w\in C$ which is not in the span of $\{v_1,\cdots,v_r\}$.  But then, $\{v_1,\cdots,v_r,w\}$ is a linearly independent subset of $C$, contradicting the assumption that $\{v_1,\cdots,v_r\}$ is *maximal*.

For the final direction, it may be easiest to prove that $2\Rightarrow 1$.  Try the following: Suppose that $C$ contains a basis $\{v_1,\cdots,v_n\}$.  Let 
$$
w=v_1+\cdots+v_n.
$$
We know that $w$ is nonzero because $v_1,\cdots,v_n$ are linearly independent.  On the other hand, $w\in C$ since $v_1,\cdots,v_n\in C$.  Moreover, $w$ is in the interior of $C$ because for any vector $z$ small enough, 
$$
z=c_1v_1+\cdots+c_nv_n
$$
where all $|c_i|<1$.  Then, $w+z\in C$ as all the coefficients of the $v_i$'s remain positive.  Now, you need a uniform bound on the $c_i$'s based on the length of $z$.  My proof of choice of this final fact would use compactness.

Comment: Consider $B(w,1) = \{y \in V: ||y-w||_{\infty}<1\}$. Now if we consider $z=y-w$ for $y \in B(w,1)$, then $y =w+z\in C$ as you mentioned. So $B(w,1) \subseteq C$ which means $int(C)$ is non-empty. If what I said is correct, then I don't think we use compactness anywhere.

Comment: That should work too, but you might need a different radius on the ball, depending on $w$.